# SharePoint field validation

Tags: jquery

Trying to validate if a "Tool" field in a sharepoint new item form equals one of 2 strings when user causes blur event.  If it is either "abc" or "zzz", then I need to popup and alert.  Not sure what I'm missing here:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $( "#Tool" ).blur(){

if($("#Tool").val() == "abc" || "zzz") {
   alert('Warning...');
}
}

}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#Tool").blur(function(){

    if($("#Tool").val() == "abc" || $("#Tool").val() == "zzz"){
        alert('warning');
    }

});
});
```